# Meteor event when Template is freshed

Tags: meteor

I am working on a Meteor project that has come custom Pagination using Sessions.  The template rendering the contents of said items is using ellipsis.js and highlight.js to do some DOM formatting.  The code looks something like thus:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        Session.setDefault("homePageSize", 10);
        Session.setDefault("homePageStart", 0);
    });
}

Template.home.articlesPaginated = function() {
    return Articles.find({published: true}, {sort: {post_date: -1}, skip: Session.get("homePageStart"), limit: Session.get("homePageSize")});
}

Template.home.rendered = function() {
    // Setup ellipsis
    $('.ellipsis').dotdotdot({
        ellipsis: '...',
        wrap: 'word',
        fallbackToLetter: true,
        after: $('a.blog_continue')
    });

    // Setup highlight.js
    $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });
}

Template.home.events({
    'click .next': function(event) {
        var offset = Session.get("homePageStart") + Session.get("homePageSize");
        if (offset < 0) {
            offset = 0;
        }
        Session.set("homePageStart", offset);
    },
    'click .prev': function(event) {
        var offset = Session.get("homePageStart") - Session.get("homePageSize");
        if (offset < 0) {
            offset = 0;
        }
        Session.set("homePageStart", offset);
    }
});
```

Pagination is working just fine, but as soon as the Template re-renders I loose all the ellipsis.js and highlight.js formatting.  I know the obvious reason is that the DOM has changed, and since the Template.render only runs once up-front and doesn't happen when the Template re-renders the DOM updates are not being applied.  So, what is the best way to trigger ellipsis.js and highlight.js after the Template is done such that it gets re-called everytime the Template re-renders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can put your `Articles` into another template, then you could apply formatting individually as they are inserted.

```js
Template.article.rendered = function () {
    // Setup ellipsis
    this.$('.ellipsis').dotdotdot({
        ellipsis: '...',
        wrap: 'word',
        fallbackToLetter: true,
        after: $('a.blog_continue')
    });

    // Setup highlight.js
    this.$('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });
};
```

Assuming your template looks something like this.

```
<template name="home">
  ...
  {{#each articlesPaginated}}
    {{> article}}
  {{/each}}
  {{> paginationControls}}
  ...
</template>
```

This has the added benefit of scoping the formatting to just the articles, rather than the entire DOM.

Comment: So, when the template is nested like this, the nested template re-calls `rendered` on the inner most template when the outer template re-draws?  If I am understanding this correctly, then this is very good to know!

Comment: Not quite. [rendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered) is only called once - when a template is inserted into the DOM. The idea here is to initialize `ellipsis` and `highlight` on individual articles as they are added. This assumes that `pre code` and `.ellipsis` DOM nodes are rendered inside of the `article` template.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb questions...still trying to wrap my head around how the flows are working.  Coming from a Java/Spring environment, this is VERY strange concepts.  Will play with this some more to see if I can use this to get it working.

Comment: Not a dumb question, it's up to me to answer clearly. Maybe printing a message to console when `home` and `article` render will help illustrate what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to listen for changes in your `Articles` collection, which is a client-side subset of the server database clipped to contain only the currently visible paginated articles.

When you detect a change in the articles subset, you'll need to retrigger initialization of `ellipsis.js` and `highlight.js`.

You could reorganize your code as follow :

First, we define the cursor declaration as a separate function on his own because we need to use it twice :

```
function articlesPaginated(){
  return Articles.find({
    published: true
  }, {
    sort: {
      post_date: -1
    },
    skip: Session.get("homePageStart"),
    limit: Session.get("homePageSize")
  });
}

Template.home.helpers({
  articlesPaginated:articlesPaginated
});
```

Then in the `rendered` callback, we need to setup a reactive computation that will depend on this cursor, so whenever the articles subset is updated to a new page, our computation will rerun.

But we need to be aware that the helper we defined on the home template returns the same cursor so it's going to be invalidated and trigger DOM refresh AT THE SAME TIME... JavaScript is single-threaded and the `Tracker.Computation` manual states that the order of execution of concurrently invalidated computations is unpredictable.

So we cannot just trigger the ellipsis/highlight initialization code in the computation because this setup code assumes that the DOM is ready, however at this precise moment we don't know if DOM manipulation has just happened before or is going to happen immediately after.

Fortunately there is a `Tracker.afterFlush` method which allows us to execute code after concurrent computations are done so we are sure that by that time DOM state is OK.

Having understand all these implications, we can write the following rendered callback :

```
Template.home.rendered=function(){
  // declare a template managed Deps.Computation
  this.autorun(function(){
    // have this reactive computation depend on the SAME cursor
    // that triggers DOM rerendering
    var articles=articlesPaginated();
    // forEach is actually the method that triggers a dependency on the cursor in this computation
    articles.forEach(function(article){
      // you can manipulate the model here if needed
    });
    // setup a callback to execute your DOM alteration code after
    // it is actually rerendered by Blaze
    Tracker.afterFlush(function(){
      // your ellipsis/highlight initialization code goes here
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Although the answer above was accepted, this is really a fantastic answer as well -- I'll try to explain why. Say that the newly rendered templates affect the sizing of the previous templates, which would require the previous templates to be told to resize. The autorun/afterFlush technique is AFAIK the *only* way to do this (as well as the correct one!). Bravo (and thanks!) to the author.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer and even corrected something about it : you need to call `forEach` on the cursor to register appropriate dependencies on the documents so the computation will invalidate when documents are removed/added/changed.