# Meteor + jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, meteor, tabs

I'm creating a simple meteor application that will create some tabs dynamically, but will also load some of the existing tabs.

I started by creating some HTML and JS files:

```
<head>
    <title>App Log Viewer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>App Log Viewer</h1>
    {{> root}}
</body>

<template name="root">
    {{> logViewerNav }}
    {{> logTabs }}
</template>

<template name="logViewerNav">
    <div class="nav">
        <form class="nav_form">
            <input type="text" name="appName" id="appName" placeholder="App Name"/>
            <input type="text" name="logPath" id="logPath" placeholder="Log Path"/>
            <input type="button" class="browse" value="Browse" />
            <input type="submit" class="add_app_button" value="Add App" />
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="logTabs">
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    {{#each apps}}
        <li><a href="#{{_id}}">{{appname}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>

    {{#each apps}}
    <div id="{{_id}}" >
        <textarea cols="100" rows="20"> </textarea>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
</template>


Apps = new Mongo.Collection('apps');

if(Meteor.isClient) {
    // Events
    Template.logViewerNav.events({
        'submit .nav_form' : function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var appName = $("#appName").val();
            var logPath = $("#logPath").val();
            Apps.insert({appname: appName, logpath: logPath});
            $("#tabs").tabs("refresh");
        }   
    }); 

    // Helpers
    Template.logTabs.helpers({
        'apps' : function(name, log) {
            return Apps.find();
        }   
    }); 

    Template.root.rendered = function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    };  
}
```

The problem is, every time I start my app, I got a partial tab rendered. I mean, it seems like the **$("#tabs").tabs();** is called before the whole list of tabs is loaded.

If I then call from the JS console **$("#tabs").tabs("refresh");** it renders the page correctly.

My question is, where is the best place for me to add the call to **$("#tabs").tabs();**

Comment: Try moving your `$("#tabs").tabs();` call to `Template.logTabs.rendered`.  This way it is called when the `logTabs` template is rendered, not the `root` template.

Comment: It was originally called that way, and I get the same result.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log('tabs: ' + $('#tabs li').length);` just before the call to `$("#tabs").tabs();`?  See what number of LIs you find.

Comment: As I expected, this is the log I get: #tabs: 0. One thing I don't understand is

Comment: <SO didn't let me edit my previous truncated comment>
As I expected, this is the log I get: 
#tabs: 1
#tabs li: 0 
One thing I don't understand is why meteor is sending rendered event before the template itself end being rendered.

Comment: I don't think surrounding templates rendered states depend on contained templates rendered states.  That is to say, in your example, the `root` template is rendered when its direct contents are rendered, and the child `logTabs` doesn't necessarily need to be rendered.  At least, this has been my experience.  Someone else more knowledgeable in Template states please speak up if I am speaking out of turn.  This would make sense because a child template can be re-rendered or even replaced without the surrounding template being re-rendered as a result.

Comment: <cont>... This is why I was suggesting moving your .rendered to the `logTabs` template and not the `root` template, as it seems misplaced there since the tabs exist in the child not the parent.  As a test, could you rename your `Template.root.rendered` to 'Template.logTabs.rendered`, leaving in the console.log, and see if the tabs are now there?

Comment: As I said before, the first version of my code didn't have the root template. I added it as a means to debug and try to get it working. I did what you suggested and the result is the same. After the rendered event is fired up, the 'tabs' div is there, but not the list.

Comment: It seems like meteor is publishing the rendered event after the static part of the template is rendered but before the reactive/dynamic part runs. If I change the dynamic code with a static one, then it works perfectly.

Comment: That runs completely counter-intuitive to what I am interpreting in the docs and what I have experienced in my own code with Meteor.  I often use the `Template.rendered` to pull things out of the DOM. Can you try switching your `rendered` back to the `logTabs` and changing your jQuery to `this.$("#tabs").tabs();`?

Comment: Ok, I think I might see the problem now.  I think what is happening is that the `apps` isn't read from Mongo until after `rendered` runs.  The `rendered` only runs the first time, and is not re-ran when the template is re-rendered, so if the 'apps' collection hasn't read yet, then your tabs would be missing when `rendered` is called.  I think what you might need to do is move the call to `$("#tabs").tabs();`, but I am not sure to where.  I'll have to think about this for a bit...

Comment: Ok, did some searching and I found a posting with a pattern that might help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486954/meteor-rendered-callback-and-appling-jquery-plugins