# Meteor Template.onRendered or Template.rendered for using a jquery library?

Tags: jquery, meteor

I want to use chosen(a jquery library) with meteor and I just need to use this code:

```
    $('#ship').chosen();
```

I tried using .onRendered but I need to wait, if I want it to work

```
Template.createTradeForm.onRendered(function(){
    //Strange bug, need to wait here or it doesn't work..
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#ship').chosen();
    }, 2000);
});
```

Same problem with this solution:

```
Template.createTradeForm.rendered = function(){
    //here again, I need to wait or it doesn't work
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#ship').chosen();
    }, 2000);
};
```

Is there any other solutions to this problem? This setTimeout isn't really good here.

**Edit**
My helper as requested

```
Template.createTradeForm.helpers({
    'getShips': function(){
        return Ship.find()
    }
});
```

Comment: how do you load the jquery library?

Comment: I load the library using meteor with this package: https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/chosen-package
The library is loaded and working but, I need to use setTimeout or It doesn't work

Comment: what's the error you get without the timeout?

Comment: have you tried the newer version (https://atmospherejs.com/eskan/chosen)?

Comment: I got no error, but my <select> disappear in the DOM

Comment: I tried with the newer version, exactly the same problem.

Comment: I think BM's diagnosis is right. I remember having had similar issues with other "post-load" decorators like this one on other occasions. It's all about making sure the data has been loaded and the elements of the template are populated. Please show your template helper code as well, where you load the data. There may be a better way than what BM suggests.

Comment: Yes, the diagnosis is right. If there this a simpler/proper way to do that, I'm open to suggestions. I edited my post to include my helper.

Comment: if you are using iron:router you can simply add a waitOn condition to not render the page until all data has arrived; if not, then BM's answer may be the best you can do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrap your code inside `Meteor.defer`, like this:

```
Template.createTradeForm.onRendered(function(){
    Meteor.defer(function(){
        $('#ship').chosen();
    });
});
```

`Meteor.defer` corresponds a `setTimeout` of `0` and it's not in docs.
It typically solve cases where something in the DOM that you're depending on has not yet rendered.

Some refs: [1](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2176), [2](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-do-i-animate-things-addingbeing-removed-from-collections), [3](https://kadira.io/academy/make-your-app-faster/#optimizing-http-calls-email-sending-and-third-party-npm-modules)

Answer (score 1):

I can only speculate on the causes as more debug information would be required. (What exactly happens without timeout? Is the DOM element being found, is the jQuery plugin `chosen` being found etc.)

First of all `rendered` and `onRendered` are the same thing and the latter is the current version while `rendered` is kept for compatibility with older code. One important thing to know that both runs exactly once only. For your problem my guess is, that you are seeing some timing issue caused by not yet loaded subscription data. Try using a [subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe) where you set a [reactive variable](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar).

```
    Meteor.subscribe('items', function() {
        readyItems.set(true);
    });
```

Then depend on the reactive variable to use the `chosen`:

```
    Tracker.autorun(function() {
        if(readyItems.get()) $('#ship').chosen();
    });
```